# Unable to play rtsp/hls videos in android app run through chrome arc

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

I am trying to play video stream in an android app run through chrome arc. But it got an error "Plugin crashed: Captured minidump".

```
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this); 
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"));
    videoView.start();
```

How can I play stream videos using the chrome arc

Answer (score 0):

Which audio encoding is used for your video? If its aac, its not yet supported.Remember file ending with .mov may not necessarily have same encoding used.